# Field value check using Regex

Tags: validation-rule

I wanna check particular word should be caps in my feedback field.
E.g: I made feedback field and if the user enter "good support", I need to check if appear the wording called good. If yes, it should be GOOD.

I mean need to change caps or notify to user. How it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to check case of words in Validation rule. You can check this website for making regular expression http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Below regular expression will check if word good exist, if so it checks if it is in UPPER case or not ? I have checked in my org and its working, let me if its not working in your case

```
AND( 
REGEX( LastName , ".*[gG][Oo][oO][dD].*"), 
NOT(CONTAINS(LastName , 'GOOD')) 
)
```

for two field, lets say if other field is firstName

```
OR(
AND( 
    REGEX( LastName , ".*[gG][Oo][oO][dD].*"), 
    NOT(CONTAINS(LastName , 'GOOD')) 
    ),
AND( 
    REGEX( FirstName , ".*[gG][Oo][oO][dD].*"), 
    NOT(CONTAINS(FirstName , 'GOOD')) 
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes. I know the reg expression but I dont know how to apply in that validaiton.  not(regex( Name , "[A-Z]+$"))

Comment: I have updated my answer with sample regex, have a look.

Comment: Realy thanks. I have doubt, Is this check the entire sentence. I mean between the sentence.  e.g "very good support" = is your code work?

Comment: It should allow only when type the caps.

Comment: Yes it will work... It will search for word anywhere. I tested it, you can mark this answer if it works...

Comment: I treid but not work.

Comment: Latname field values is : "this is good", but the validation not showing error.

Comment: It shoudl show the error like, good should be caps (GOOD). How to make it? Please do not hesitate.

Comment: But it is working for me.. I tested it again. In Lead Object, in lastname i have entered "this is good" and there is validation rule defined on this. It is throwing error as expected

Comment: Oh. Ok how to add the another field as well in this code.

Comment: If you want same validation on two fields, you can create 2 validation rules for those 2 fields.

Comment: Oh. I think we can check two field in the same validation rule. Can you amend in your code please.

Comment: I have updated answer.

Comment: Really thanks. I will use this code. you are the rock :). Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow rule and a field update using formula that will replace your keywords with uppercase. You can use the `SUBSTITUTE` function in your field update formula: `SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text)`